# not able to open jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When trying to launch jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator using the Launch button, by default it opens the Adobe Acrobat Reader window. I am using windows 11

[image]

Comment: These files are PDFs, are you sure you're trying to open a notebook? Not sure what this screenshot is meant to show...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem today and I just figured it out. Right-click on any website and hit 'Save as'. This will download a .html file. Find it in file folder. My default application for opening it was adobe acrobat. Right-click on the file and go to properties. Type of file should be .html. Under 'opens with' change it from Adobe Acrobat to any browser. Save. Now try to launch Jupyter notebook again, Hope it's as simple as that and works for you as well!